# If fn convergence in measure on Ek, then fn convergence in measure on E= ⋃ Ek

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E_{k}$ be measurable, and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_{k})< \infty$ 
If for every $E_{k}$, we have $f_{n}$ convergent in measure on $E_{k}$
prove $f_{n}$ convergence in measure on $E = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} E_{k}$

It's in Lesbesgue measure, $m(E_{k})$ means measure of $E_{k}$.
I have no idea how to start, help me please!

Comment: Start by writing down what you need to prove without using a new definition (e.g. in terms of limits of numbers but not in terms of convergence of measurable functions).

Comment: We need to prove lim(m{x in E | |fn(x)-f(x)|>=ε}) = 0 right?

Comment: Yep. Now let me actually give a substantive hint: $m(\{ x \in E : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon \}) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(\{ x \in E_k : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon \})$. (You have equality if $E_k$ are disjoint, of course.)

Comment: Yes~ and than?....XD

Comment: Well, now you can make each term of the sum small by taking $n$ large, just using the given information. Can you choose them to be small *enough* that the sum as a whole is small?

Comment: $m(\{ x \in E : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon \}) \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(\{ x \in E_k : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon \})\leq\sum_{k=1}^n m(\{ x \in E_k : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon \})\leq\ (epsilon/n)*n = epsilon$  Is that right?

Comment: No, you can't reduce to a finite sum. You need the infinite sum of all those measures to converge to something small, which means the summands themselves must be rather small indeed...

Comment: Also, you will need to exploit the fact that the measure of $E$ is finite. Without that, you may be able to choose numbers $N_k$ such that if $n \geq N_k$ then $m(\{ x \in E_k : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon \}) \leq \delta_k$ but you may have $N_k \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$ in which case the proof breaks down.

Comment: That much is just the definition of the limit. The "standard measure theory trick" that you want to achieve here is to make $m(\{ x \in E_k : |f_n(x)-f(x)| \geq \epsilon \}) \leq \frac{\delta}{2^k}$ where $\delta>0$ is arbitrary. But you won't be able to do this using just convergence in measure, you will need the finite measure hypothesis. What other theorems do you know that use finite measure? The one I have in mind has a name...

Comment: I still can't figure it out...Can you give me the answer and let me ask you?

Comment: The result I'm thinking of is Egorov's theorem.

Comment: Egorov's theorem is about  f_{n} convergence almost everywhere then f_{n} convergence uniformly. It seems not relevant to this problem?

Comment: I thought there was a convergence in measure version but I seem to have misremembered. Anyway, now I see an alternate way to proceed. One can show that on a finite measure space, a sequence converges in measure if and only if every subsequence has a further subsequence which converges a.e. With this proposition in hand, since you have convergence in measure on each of the $E_k$, you can use the usual diagonal argument to build such a further subsequence from any given subsequence.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $\epsilon>0$ and let $\alpha>0$.  Then there exists $N_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N_0$ we have
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=n+1} m(E_k)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.
\end{align}
Next, for each $k = 1, \ldots, n$ there exists $N_k$ such that 
\begin{align}
m\{x \in E_k \mid |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\alpha\}<\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}
\end{align}
for all $n>N_k$. Lastly, choose $N=\max_{0 \leq j \leq N_n} N_j$, then we see for all $m>N$
\begin{align}
m\{x \in E\mid |f(x)-f_m(x)|\geq \alpha\} \leq&\ \sum^n_{k=1}m\{x \in E_k \mid |f(x)-f_m(x)|\geq \alpha\}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\
\leq&\ \sum^n_{k=1}\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}< \epsilon.
\end{align}
Hence $f_n\rightarrow f$ in measure on $E$.